# Use SwiftyJSON to convert tuple array to JSON string

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I wanted to convert a simple array of tuples like this to a JSON string using SwiftyJSON:

```
let  tupleArray: [(Int, Int)] = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]

let tupleArrayAsJsonSttring = JSON(tupleArray).rawString(.utf8)
```

But nil is returned.  I'm stumped as i thought this would be easy. Anyone done this before?

Comment: There is no tuple in json as far as I know, how do you expect the final json to be, could you add an example? Also, why not use Codable?

Comment: Yes, thanks Joakim, you're right. I realise now that I don't actually need a JSON string, a simple string representation is fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't need a JSON string after all and as Joakim stated, there's no tuple in JSON.
I ended up just doing this:

```
let arr = tupleArray.map { "("+String($0.0)+","+String($0.1)+")"}
let str = arr.joined(separator: ",")
```

which gave me:

```
"(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)"
```

Comment: Or `let str = tupleArray.map { "\($0)"}.joined(separator: ",")`